# C/C++ bit array resolution transform algorithms

Tags: c++, c, arrays, loops, bitset

Anyone aware of any algorithms to up/down convert bit arrays?

ie: when the resolution is 1/16:

every 1 bit = 16 bits. (low resolution to high resolution)

```
1010 -> 1111111111111111000000000000000011111111111111110000000000000000
```

and reverse, 16 bits = 1 bit (high resolution to low resolution)

```
1111111111111111000000000000000011111111111111110000000000000000 -> 1010
```

Right now I am looping bit by bit which is not efficient. Using a whole 64-bit word would be better but run into issues when the word isn't divisible by resolution equally (some bits may spill over to the next word).

C++:

```
std::vector<uint64_t> bitset;
```

C:

```
uint64_t *bitset = calloc(total_bits >> 6, sizeof(uint64_t)); // free() when done
```

which is accessed using:

```
const uint64_t idx = bit >> 6;
const uint64_t pos = bit % 64;

const bool value = (bitset[idx] >> pos) & 1U;
```

and set/clear:

```
bitset[idx] |= (1UL << pos);
bitset[idx] &= ~(1UL << pos);
```

and the OR (or AND/XOR/AND/NOT) of two bitsets of same resolution are done using the full 64-bit word:

```
bitset[idx] |= source.bitset[idx];
```

I am dealing with large enough bitsets (2+ billion bits) that I'm looking for any efficiency in the loops. One way I found to optimize the loop is to check each word using `__builtin_popcountll`, and skip ahead in the loop:

```
for (uint64_t bit = 0; bit < total_bits; bit++)
{ 
   const uint64_t idx = bit >> 6;
   const uint64_t pos = bit % 64;

   const uint64_t bits = __builtin_popcountll(bitset[idx]);

   if (!bits)
   {
      i += 63;
      continue;
   }
   // process
}
```

**I'm looking for algorithms/techniques more than code examples. But if you have code to share, I won't say no. Any academic research papers would be appreciated too.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `std::vector<uint64_t> bitset;` not in C you aren't. Be cautious and make sure each language is relevant when  you tag extra languages. If you truly don't care what language is used, tag as  `language-agnostic`.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301 for your comment. You can replace `std::vector<uint64_t> bitset` with `uint64_t *bitset` and it will work in C.

Comment: Converting an N-bit signal to M bits where N != M with minimal introduction of noise is actually a huge topic. One big category of research dealing with this problem is Delta-Sigma (also called Sigma-Delta) modulation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation

Comment: This is awesome, thanks @gene for putting a name to this problem! I will be googling this some more now :)

Answer (score 0):

Does the resolution always between 1/2 and 1/64? Or even 1/32? Because if you need very long sequence, you might need more loop nesting which might cause some slow down.

Are you sequence always very long (millions of bits) or this is a maximum but usually your sequences are shorter? When doing high to low resolution, can you assume that data is valid or not.

Here are some tricks:

```
uint64_t one = 1;
uint64_t n_one_bits = (one << n) - 1u; // valid for 0 to 63; not sure for 64
```

If your sequence are so long, you might want to check if `n` is some power of 2 and have more optimized code for those cases.

You might find some other useful tricks here:

https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

So if your resolution is 1/16, you don't need to loop individual 16 bits but you can check all 16 bits at once. Then you can repeat for next group again and again.

If the number is not an a divider of 64, you can shift bits as appropriate each time you would cross the 64 bits boundary. Say, that your resolution is 1/5, then you could process 60 bits, then shift 4 remaining bit and combine with following 60 bits.

If you can assume that data is valid, then you don't even need to shift the original number as you can pick the value of the appropriate bit each time.

Comment: Thanks @Phil1970 for your comment. The resolution can be anything, 1/2 or even 2/4 and my bit sequences can range anywhere from 1^9 to 1^15.  I wish the resolution was power of 2, it would make things a bit easier :)